# Dynamic styles within a scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, themes

I have a site that is intended to be combined  with third party skins defining headers, navigation, etc.  My site has stylesheets, the third party has stylesheets.  I combine the two and predictably get a big giant mess.

What I would like to do is say, "Apply this set of stylesheets to this portion of the page, and these other ones to this one." I do not want to use frames to accomplish this.

An obvious solution is to prefix all of my own styles with a container's id. Because it is a large site with hundreds of styles, this would be a pain to do and maintain.

So really, what I want to do is to do something like that dynamically.

One option is on the back end, parse the stylesheet, and modify it, adding the id of the container before each style name. The other, with javascript, parsing the stylesheet into memory and modifying in place. I like the front end option better.

Can anyone think of a better option? Some jquery plugin that says, 
    $().apply_styles_from_file();

Or some layout solution that solves the issue of mixing the sheets?

Or good libraries that can be trusted to parse and modify stylesheets in place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my research, I determined that there is no elegant way to solve this. What I ultimately did is use a server-side solution to rewrite the entire set of stylesheets I have and add an class to every definition:

```
   A{} becomes .myclass A{}
   .foo becomes .myclass foo{}
   #thispage .bar becomes .myclass #thispage .bar{}
```

I did this via a handler, which looks for the file, then if not found or modified since the last compilation, rewrites it. I used the perl module CSS::Simple to do the rewriting.

Then I wrapped the core content in the class:

```
   <!-- header here -->
   <div class="myclass">
     <!-- content here -->
   </div>
   <!-- footer here -->
```

Now anything I have outside of this special class gets its own styles without interference from mine. I can now have pages where 3rd party styles dominate (skipping the wrapper above and only wrapping the pieces I want) or those where mine do as above, while the header can come from the 3rd party.

This is horrible and clunky.  :-( There needs to be some context in future versions of CSS. But it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I think no matter what you do you're going to have to have containers and styles that apply to only the elements within that container. Even if you do the Javascript-based method you're asking for, you still have to define somewhere which elements are to be affected, which would only get more and more complicated as time goes on.

Therefore, I would just plain avoid a JS-based solution, and instead go for a server-side language like PHP which would allow you to set scopes on individual views, then render the views separately, like so:

```
     <div id="main">
         <? render('view' => 'users.php', 'scope' => 'users'); ?>
         <? render('view' => 'games.php', 'scope' => 'games'); ?>
     </div>
```

The render method could then wrap the view in a div and ensure that it has a container with the scope specified. Depending on what the view looks like, the output could look something like:

```
     <div id="main">
         <div class="users">Users go here.</div>
         <div class="games">Games go here</div>
     </div>
```

Then later on, should you decide to add another games section, you can simply re-declare the scope in the new rendered partial, and it would have the same CSS scope as the earlier one.

You could have CSS files that represent each scope (e.g. users.css) to help separate out the styles that belong to each other.

That's one way to handle it, I think, and it's the best thing I can come up with on the spot.

Good luck, and if you find a better solution, I'd love to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
#green-bg 
{
    background-color: green;
}

#red-bg 
{
    background-color: red;
}

<div id="red" class="color-selector">Apply Red Background</div>
<div id="green" class="color-selector">Apply Green Background</div>

<div id="content">I need a background color!</div>

$('.color-selector').click(function() {
    $('#content').addClass('#' + this.id + '-bg');        
});
```

I should also mention that aside from naming convention I don't believe there is any  way to "ignore" a stylesheet that has been loaded if its properties match your element's request.

Ex. If you have two stylesheets that both have a `h1` declaration, your `h1` elements will be styled according to whichever one wins the collision.  The only way to differentiate would be for each stylesheet to have its properties named accordingly (eg. `h1.light`, `h1.dark`) and you apply them in the fashion I described above.

Answer (score 0):

What about if the user_made CSS gets a `!important` rule?

Just for this:

The user customizes the allowed area and applies it to his/her page - in the back a css-file will be created with !important-rules for the modified areas.

Should work, but you should deny any css-hack you don't want to have.
(like former Myspace ;) ).